Modificar un arbol desde otra funcion con un apuntador a una rama de este
Estoy en C y tengo una funcion que me busca en un arbol un nodo, despues a este nodo lo elimino, no se como hacerle para que este nodo tambien se elimine en el arbol ya que al momento de imprimir el arbol este me saca basura en la memoria asignada del nodo eliminado, sin embargo no deberia de devolver nada por que se supone vale NULL, quiero que al momento de eliminar el nodo tambien se elimine en el arbol sin imprimirme basura. alguien tiene ideas usando este mismo diseño (con apuntadores y usando diferentes funciones
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_150 150

typedef struct nod
{
    char *nombre;
    int num;
    struct nod *izq, *der;
}sArbol;

sArbol *crea_arbol();

char *ingresa_nombre();
int pide_numero();

void inserta_arbol(sArbol **arb, sArbol *nuevo);

void edita_nodo(sArbol **arb);

sArbol *busca_nodo(sArbol **arb, int num_busqueda);

void elimina_nodo(sArbol **arb);

void imprime_nodo(sArbol *cab);
void imprime_inorden(sArbol *arb);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    sArbol *arb = NULL, *nuevo = NULL;
    int num_busqueda;
    
    nuevo = crea_arbol();
    inserta_arbol(&arb, nuevo);
    nuevo = crea_arbol();
    inserta_arbol(&arb, nuevo);
    nuevo = crea_arbol();
    inserta_arbol(&arb, nuevo);
    
    imprime_inorden(arb);
    
    num_busqueda = pide_numero();
    nuevo = busca_nodo(&arb, num_busqueda);
    
    if(nuevo == NULL)
    {
        printf("No se encontro el nodo en el arbol =(.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Se encontro el numero.\n");
        elimina_nodo(&nuevo);
        imprime_nodo(nuevo);
    }
    
    imprime_inorden(arb);
    
    
    
    return 0;
}


sArbol *crea_arbol()
{
    sArbol *aux = NULL;
    aux = (sArbol*) malloc(sizeof(sArbol));
    
    aux->nombre = ingresa_nombre();
    aux->num = pide_numero();
    aux->izq = NULL;
    aux->der = NULL;
    
    return aux;
}

char *ingresa_nombre()
{
    char *nombre = NULL;
    nombre = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_150);
    
    printf("Escribe el nombre del nodo:");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(nombre, MAX_150, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    nombre[strlen(nombre) - 1] = '\0';
    realloc(nombre, strlen(nombre));
    
    return nombre;
}

int pide_numero()
{
    int numero;
    
    printf("Escribe el numero a insertar al arbol:");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    
    return numero;
}

void inserta_arbol(sArbol **arb, sArbol *nuevo) //No balanceado
{
    if(*arb == NULL)
    {
        *arb = nuevo;
    }
    else
    {
        if(nuevo->num <= (*arb)->num)
        {
            inserta_arbol(&((*arb)->izq), nuevo);
        }
        else
        {
            inserta_arbol(&((*arb)->der), nuevo);
        }
    }
}

void edita_nodo(sArbol **arb)
{
    int nuevo_num;
    nuevo_num = pide_numero();
    
    (*arb)->num = nuevo_num;
}

void elimina_nodo(sArbol **arb)
{
    sArbol *aux = NULL;
    
    if((*arb)->izq == NULL && (*arb)->der == NULL)
    {
        free((*arb)->nombre);
        (*arb)->nombre = NULL;
        free(*arb);
        *arb = NULL;
    }
}
sArbol *busca_nodo(sArbol **arb, int num_busqueda)
{
    sArbol *aux = NULL;
    aux = *arb;
    
    if(aux->num == num_busqueda || aux == NULL)
    {
        return aux;
    }
    else
    {
        if(num_busqueda < aux->num)
        {
            return busca_nodo(&(aux->izq), num_busqueda);
        }
        else
        {
            return busca_nodo(&(aux->der), num_busqueda);
        }
    }
        
}

void imprime_inorden(sArbol *arb)
{
    if(arb != NULL)
    {
        imprime_inorden(arb->izq);
        printf("El nombre del nodo es: %s con valor de %d.\n", arb->nombre, arb->num);
        imprime_inorden(arb->der);
    }
}

void imprime_nodo(sArbol *arb)
{
    if(arb != NULL)
    {
        printf("El nombre del nodo es: %s con valor de %d.\n", arb->nombre, arb->num);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("El nodo esta vacio.\n");
    }
}


Me parece que solo liberas la memoria por el nodo, pero no modificas el (los) otro(s) nodo(s) que apuntas al que acabas de eliminar.

Si eso es lo que pasa y sabes de alguna manera en la que puedo modificar los otros nodos?, usando el diseño de el nodo que apunta al arbol?

Cuando buscas el nodo, debes recordar el nodo previo y poner a NULL el puntero (izquierdo o derecho) que te lleva a él.

graciaas se me habia olvidado eso

No hay una única solución. Podrías agregar un puntero al padre, de ese modo tendrías toda la información necesaria en el mismo nodo:
typedef struct nod
{
    char *nombre;
    int num;
    struct nod *izq, *der, *padre;
} sArbol;

O en lugar de devolver un puntero al nodo, ya que solo necesitas cambiar la variable que apunta al nodo puedes devolver un puntero a esa misma variable.
sArbol** busca_nodo(sArbol** arb, int num_busqueda)
{
    sArbol *aux = NULL;
    aux = *arb;
    
    if(aux->num == num_busqueda || aux == NULL) {
        return arb;
    }
    else if(num_busqueda < aux->num) {
        return busca_nodo(&(aux->izq), num_busqueda);
    }
    else {
        return busca_nodo(&(aux->der), num_busqueda);
    }
}

Para eliminar la referencia al nodo solo tienes que hacer así:
sArbol** variable = busca_nodo(...);
...
free(*variable);
*variable = 0;

Por cierto, fflush(stdin) no funciona como esperas en todos los compiladores. Considera utilizar alguna alternativa portable.
